# !pip install rpy2==2.3.0 error Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, rpy2

I run the following code

```
!pip install rpy2==2.3.0 error
```

received this error

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\ramic\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3o_vlkru\rpy2\

I have done the following

```
!pip install --user --upgrade setuptools
```

then

```
!pip install ez_setup
```

I tried to reinstall using

```
!pip install rpy2==2.3.0
```

It still gave me the same error message.

Comment: try adding the `--user` flag, so your install command would be `pip install --user rpy2==2.3.0`

Comment: @Campiotti Still same error

Comment: Hmm is there anything more to the error it prints out? Anything you might've cut out when you pasted it into the StackOverflow question - usually they should be a decent bit longer.

Also what console are you using to run your `pip install` commands?  Windows CMD?

Comment: @Campiotti I think I figure it out! it needs to be installed on Anaconda first

Comment: alright, that's great!  I saw that you made an answer for your question post - if your answer worked, then please mark it as an answer by clicking on the big check-mark at the top of your answer post.

Comment: @Campiotti It says "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" so unfortunately I can not do it now

Comment: alright in that case try and remember to do it tomorrow - this will help others having the same issues since they'll see which post is marked as an answer immediately.
Enjoy your coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this involves R packages, I was able to sort this out by running Anaconda Prompt as an administrator

```
conda install -c r rpy2
```

Then you can go to jupyter notebook using python and can simply do

```
!pip install rpy2
```

This worked for me